# What properties of a voting method is best for deciding what movie to watch among a small group of people?

Tags: game-theory, voting-theory, social-choice-theory

Almost every night me and my friends get together to watch a movie.

#### Current Method:

Each person (<10) picks 5 movies they want to watch and we vote on them. Each person gets around 7 votes which they must use to pick a movie. They are allowed to vote on their own movies. We then tally up the votes and the movie with the most votes wins. In case of a tie (which is common, sometimes with many movies with 2-3 votes each) we redo the vote just with the tied movies and pick the number of votes based on simple intuition (guessing really).

This method of voting is not satisfactory for the following reasons:

1. Movies that people vote for as a throw away vote sometimes win.
2. Ties are common with a large spread.
3. It is easy to make dishonest votes in order for your movie to win.
4. Sometimes a voter will boycott a movie because how unsatisfied they are with the vote.

#### My Research:

I was looking at wikipedia for different methods of voting and came across this table:
[Table with properties of different voting methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zluF8.png) I had a hard time understanding some of the properties and if it would be beneficial or unbeneficial to my scenario.

#### Scenario:

- Each voter picks N (N > 1) movies to vote on
- 2-10 voters (usually at least 3)
- There must be one winner
- voters prefer their own movies.

I was wondering given the following scenario What properties of a voting method would be ideal? I would like to maximize the following:

1. Members of the vote should feel strongly about the winning movie. (perhaps there is a way to quantify this?)
2. works well when number of candidates is >= to number of voters.
3. Given possibly large number of movies to vote on vote must be relatively quick to complete.
4. Gaming the vote is hard to do as an individual.
5. Voters only have to vote once.

Comment: Ranked choice voting. Let people rank the movies they want to watch. They can rank as many movies as they want, and leave the rest unranked. Count everyone's first choice. If none is a majority, throw out the lowest vote-getter(s) and replace any votes for it with the person's next choice (if no next choice, that person is out of luck). Continue until a movie has a majority of remaining votes. This sounds complicated, but it will be less work than what you currently do. Also, accept the fact that not everyone will be happy, no matter what you do. Let them leave.

Comment: You posed a question in the title, and the body of your Question provides context for your wanting a recommendation on a voting method.  But the title actually seems to call for information about *properties* of a voting method that are "best".  I'm sure the problem is clear in your own mind, but Readers may well have difficulty deciding whether your concern is for a voting method recommendation or explanation of some material on properties of them generally that you found hard to understand.